# Formatting a 2d list, read in from file

Tags: python, list, format

Using python 2.7, I can read multiple csv's in from list of file names with this...

```
empty = []
for i in items:
    with open(i) as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file, dialect='excel')
        for row in reader:
            print row
```

This prints nicely...

```
['myfile.csv', 'a', '4', '50.0', 10.0]
['myfile2.csv', 'b', '2', '20.0', 50.0]
......
```

Now if I want to append this printed list to an empty 2nd list (empty=[]), how can I format it so it looks like the output above (with nice neat columns). At the moment its a big, long continuous row of output when I add `empty.append(row)`

Comment: What does your `csv` records look like?

Comment: 5 columns and many rows?

Comment: Have you tried printing w/ the `pprint` module? http://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html

Comment: Can you show an example of the `big, long continuous row of output` appended to `empty`?

Comment: @Satoru.Logic ..well it's simply like ['myfile.csv', 'a', '4', '50.0', 10.0],['myfile2.csv', 'b', '2', '20.0', 50.0],['myfile2.csv', 'f', '0', '20.0', 00.0],[.....on and on.... I'm trying to get each one of those printed to a new line like in the OP. Thanks

Comment: @user2395759 Aren't you already printing the way you want by iterating each reader?

Answer (score 0):

Try using pprint:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint as pp
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7]
>>> pp(a)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7]

>>> b = [a, a, a]
>>> pp(b)
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7]]
>>>
```